# Check if timerange covers now() in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column named `office_hours` with the datatype of `timerange`, which was defined via:

```
create type timerange as range (subtype = time)
```

I want to write a query that checks whether or not `now()` is included in that time range. What I'm looking for is something similar to:

```
select now() <@ office_hours from users where office_hours is not null;
```

Whenever I try to run that query I get this error message:

[image: dbeaver error message]

What is the right way to query whether or not a timerange contains `now()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message was giving a good hint already. Since you have a create a `time` range, you would need to cast `now()` to time before checking for containment.

Consider:

```
select now()::time <@ office_hours from users where office_hours is not null;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tU5KAiKWvkEmWp535zPi2d/0)**:

```
create type timerange as range (subtype = time);
select now(), now()::time <@ timerange('[20:00,23:00]') contained;
```

Yields:

```
| now                      | contained |
| ------------------------ | --------- |
| 2019-04-05T20:54:13.113Z | true      |
```

Comment: Or use `localtime` instead of `now()::time`